# Production-mode to developer-mode error

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1.7, developer-mode, production-mode

After the development of Magento 2 store, I push my site on production mode and perform all the speedup tweak's like merge JS/CSS etc..

After this, my site is working very well without any JavaScript error in production mode.

My client wants to install one more extension in this store.
So I want to ask what is the procedure to follow to install the new extension in production mode site.

- Should we install the extension in the production mode without of the JS/CSS merging?
- Should we turn off the JS/CSS merging and change the production mode to the developer mode and install the new extension?

Because when we change the production mode to developer mode, we get many JavaScript errors and site not running properly.

Please suggest.

Comment: Don't install extension in production mode

Comment: When I change the production mode to developer I getting JS errors

Comment: Disable the JS merge ad make sure static content generated properly

Comment: Merging and minification of js will not work in developer mode.

Comment: I have disabled the Merging and minification of js before switch to developer mode.